# How to run Vuetify.js toolbar title with router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, toolbar, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify.js.
I wanted to application title to link to top menu.
But in /route shop and /discount the HogeHoge button changed toggled state.
Is there any way to collect this?

```
<v-toolbar app>
  <v-toolbar-title class="mr-5">
    <v-btn flat to="/">HogeHoge</v-btn>
  </v-toolbar-title>
  <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
    <v-btn flat to="/shop">shop</v-btn>
    <v-btn flat to="/discount">discount</v-btn>
  </v-toolbar-items>
</v-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply edit v-toolbar-title tag to include the following:

```
<v-toolbar-title style="cursor: pointer" @click="$router.push('/')" >
```

Comment: Simple and that is it. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! This allowed me to avoid having to override link styles

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by simply wrapping it in a `router-link`.

```
<v-toolbar app clipped-left>
    <router-link to="/page1">
      <v-toolbar-title>
         Title
      </v-toolbar-title>
   </router-link>
</v-toolbar>
```

In `Nuxt js` you can do like this:

```
<nuxt-link to="/page1">
    <v-toolbar-title>
         Title
    </v-toolbar-title>
</nuxt-link>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add **exact** as prop, as:

```
<v-btn flat to="/shop" exact>shop</v-btn>
<v-btn flat to="/discount" exact>discount</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<router-link to="/home" tag="div" class="v-toolbar__title">Home</router-link>
```

And you can do it with any element. Just you need to know which vuetify class name you should use.
If you dont know what class name is it just at first try implement normal element which will be a router link.

```
<v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
```

Open your dev tools browser and copy class name (and tag also).
[image]
Now you can do the trick with router link.

Answer (score 0):

I could self solve this.
Doing active-class noting to root route.

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1947

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it. I followed a mix of vuetify and vue-router official documentation.

```
<v-toolbar-title style="cursor: pointer">
    <router-link v-slot="{navigate}" :to="{ name:'Home' }" custom>
      <span role="link" @click="navigate" @keypress.enter="navigate">
        Home
      </span>
    </router-link>
  </v-toolbar-title>
```

It is important to highlight some things on this answer:

1. <router-link>'s tag prop is deprecated and has been removed in Vue Router 4. Use the v-slot API to remove this warning: https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link
2. Using span instead of nothing removes issues with formatting.
3. This also removes the warning about *NavigationDuplicated* from vue-router.